# Check if set value present in file line

Tags: python

I would like to iterate over a set of values and check if each value is present in a file. Because the file is over 1GB in size I read one line at a time. The following loop doesn't create an exception but doesn't produce the desired results either.

Also, if I break out of the loop, will the line 'counter' get reset?

```
values = ('a', 'q', 'z', 'c')
in_file = r'C:\test.txt'
temp_list = []

with open(in_file, 'rb') as file:
    for v in values:
        for line in file:
            if line == v:
                temp_list.append(v)
                break
```

Comment: Why do you `break` when the condition is `true`. Shouldn't it be in the `else`?

Comment: @Unni - I `break `because I want to find out if a set value is in the file. If `true`, then I want to move onto the next value in the set